# How do I offset underline using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to place to place a text underline without using CSS. I've  used `<p><u>text</u></p>` and `class="text-decoration-underline">`, but neither seem to have an option to offset so that the text sits a few px lower than default.

Only other method I've seen is `class="list-group list-group-flush">` but it takes the length of the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the border and padding (pb-1, pb-2, etc...) utility classes...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class="m-5">
  <span class="border-bottom pb-1">text with underline</span> and other text
</p>
```

[Responsive demo](https://codeply.com/p/ffO6EsWvz0)